# Remove suffixes from numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to remove suffixes "m", "k", "b", or "%" from numbers in Javascript.

I've successfully matched all digits which are followed by the letters I care about:

```
\b[\d\.]+[mkb%]\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Gka1mxwzGObp08Rq)

Given this set:

```
10.0 20.0k 30k 40k40 50m 60m6 m 70 m 80b80b 90%
```

I'd like to remove the suffixes from the 20, 30, 50, 90, and the trailing one from the 80. (the others don't have a word boundary after them)

I'm not clear on how to capture (and then remove) only the suffix portion of this. Little help?

Comment: If you had `40k40m`, would you want to remove that `m` or not?

Comment: Do you want to remove the suffixes or the number before the suffixes? Your question states it both ways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\b`  at front and also capture only the digit part. So that the captured chars would be back-referenced in the replacement part.

```
string.replace(/\b([\d\.]+)[mkb]\b/g, "$1")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cI0sG8/1)

Comment: Oh, I see. You replace the entire match with the `$1` capture group. Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: I have a little problem extending this to the `%` suffix: `"40%".replace(/\b([\d\.]+)[mkb%]\b/ig, '$1')` does not replace, "40k".replace(/\b([\d\.]+)[mkb%]\b/ig, '$1') does.

Comment: @SimplGy you need to remove the second `\b`, `"40%".replace(/\b([\d\.]+)[mkb%]/ig, '$1')`

Comment: Yeah. I realized that because `%` is not a word like character, it doesn't think it's found a word boundary. Changes the behavior a lot, and detecting spaces, end of string, and start of string is a lot to add...

Comment: you may also use `"40%".replace(/\b([\d\.]+)[mkb%](?!\S)/ig, '$1')`

Answer (score 3):

Put the capture group around just the numeric part, not the whole thing.

```
/([\d.]+)[mkb]\b/
```